# Can you provide additional tags for documents using TaggedLineDocument?

Tags: gensim, doc2vec

When training a doc2vec model using a corpus in the `TaggedDocument` class, you can provide a list of tags. When the doc2vec model is trained it learns a vector representation for the tags. For example you could have one tag representing the document, and another representing some classification that can be shared between documents.

How would one provide additional tags when streaming a corpus using `TaggedLineDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TaggedLineDocument` class only considers documents to be one per line, with a single tag that is their line-number.

If you want more tags, you'll have to provide your own iterable which does that. It should only be a few lines of code, depending on where your other tags come from. You can use the source for `TaggedLineDocument` – which is itself only 9 lines of Python code –as a model to build on:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/e4199cb4e9a90df44ca59c1d0505b138caa21951/gensim/models/doc2vec.py#L1126

Note: while supplying ore than one tag per document is a natural extension of the original 'Paragraph Vectors' approach, and often can provide benefits, sometimes it also 'dilutes' the salience of each tag's vector – which will be a special concern as the average number of tags per document grows, or the model acquires many more tags than unique documents. So be sure to comparatively evaluate whether any multiple-tag strategy is helping or hurting, in different modes, and whether things like pre-known categories work better as extra tags or known-labels for some later steps.